# How to calculate the mean of a dataframe column and find the top 10%

Tags: apache-spark, scala

I am very new to Scala and Spark, and am working on some self-made exercises using baseball statistics. I am using a case class create a RDD and assign a schema to the data, and am then turning it into a DataFrame so I can use SparkSQL to select groups of players via their stats that meet certain criteria.

Once I have the subset of players I am interested in looking at further, I would like to find the mean of a column; eg Batting Average or RBIs. From there I would like to break all the players into percentile groups based on their average performance compared to all players; the top 10%, bottom 10%, 40-50%

I've been able to use the DataFrame.describe() function to return a summary of a desired column (mean, stddev, count, min, and max) all as strings though. Is there a better way to get just the mean and stddev as Doubles, and what is the best way of breaking the players into groups of 10-percentiles?

So far my thoughts are to find the values that bookend the percentile ranges and writing a function that groups players via comparators, but that feels like it is bordering on reinventing the wheel.

I have the following imports currently:

```
 import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD 
 import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext 
 import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext} 
 import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
```

Comment: Have you checked the [scaladoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)? It has an example for average and max: `.agg(avg(people("salary")), max(people("age")))`. With sorting you can probably find (using `skip` and `take`) the percentiles, but there might be faster options.

Comment: I had seen this previously in the scaladocs.  When I try to use them like the example I receive and error `not found: value avg` and `not found: value max`

Comment: What are your imports? It might be easier to help if there is an example and you describe what were the problem.

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD`  
`import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext`  
`import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}`  
`import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat`

Comment: The following [test](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameAggregateSuite.scala) might help start using DataFrame functions. It seems you have to import the `org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` too. (BTW.: I think the additional information is better added to the question itself and it is enough to add a comment after edit.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is the import you need, and how to get the mean for a column named "RBIs":

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(avg($"RBIs")).show()
```

For the standard deviation, see
[scala - Calculate the standard deviation of grouped data in a Spark DataFrame - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789939/calculate-the-standard-deviation-of-grouped-data-in-a-spark-dataframe)

For grouping by percentiles, I suggest defining a new column via a user-defined function (UDF), and using groupBy on that column.  See

- [Spark SQL and DataFrames - Spark 1.5.1 Documentation - udf registration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#udf-registration-moved-to-sqlcontextudf-java--scala)

Answer (score 7):

This also returns the average of the selected column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean
df.select(mean(df("ColumnName"))).show()
+----------------+
| avg(ColumnName)|
+----------------+
|230.522453845909|
+----------------+
```

Comment: `mean` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

In Pyspark you can just use the function avg and the name of the column without $.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg
avg_file_size= float(df.select(avg("col_name")).collect()[0][0])
print(avg_file_size)
```